# jQuery Always Loads Stylesheet from Cache

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

We have a web app that uses Kendo UI and allows the user to switch themes. We've had to add a custom CSS sheet for each different Kendo theme.

We use jQuery appendTo("head") to load our custom stylesheets. The issue is that as we make changes to these sheets, jQuery continues to load them from cache, even when they have actually changed. We're specifically having this problem in Google Chrome. I haven't tested any other browsers but i suspect the problem exists in other browsers too.

```
function changeTheme(skinName, animate) {
var doc = document,
    kendoLinks = $("link[href*='kendo.']", doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]),
    commonLink = kendoLinks.filter("[href*='kendo.common']"),
    skinLink = kendoLinks.filter(":not([href*='kendo.common'])"),
    href = location.href,
    skinRegex = /kendo\.\w+(\.min)?\.css/i,
    vmSkinRegex = /kendo\.\w+(\.min)?\.css/i,
    extension = skinLink.attr("rel") === "stylesheet" ? ".css" : ".less",
    url = commonLink.attr("href").replace(skinRegex, "kendo." + skinName + "$1" + extension),
    vmUrl = commonLink.attr("href").replace(vmSkinRegex, "kendo." + skinName + "$1" + ".vm" + extension);

vmUrl = vmUrl.replace(".min", "");

function preloadStylesheet(file, callback) {
    var element = $("<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='" + file + "' />").appendTo("head");

    setTimeout(function () {
        callback();
        element.remove();
    }, 100);
}

function replaceTheme() {
    var oldSkinName = $(doc).data("kendoSkin"),
        newLink, vmLink;

    if (doc.createStyleSheet) {
        // < IE 11
        newLink = doc.createStyleSheet(url);
        vmLink = doc.createStyleSheet(vmUrl);
    } else if ($('html').hasClass('k-ie')) {
        // IE 11

        newLink = $("<link/>");
        newLink.appendTo("head");
        newLink.attr({ type: 'text/css', rel: 'stylesheet' })
            .attr('href', url);

        vmLink = $("<link/>");
        vmLink.appendTo("head");
        vmLink.attr({ type: 'text/css', rel: 'stylesheet' })
            .attr('href', vmUrl);

    } else {
        // All the smart browsers.
        newLink = skinLink.eq(0).clone().attr("href", url);
        vmLink = skinLink.eq(0).clone().attr("href", vmUrl);
    }

    newLink.insertBefore(skinLink[0]);
    vmLink.insertBefore(skinLink[0]);

    skinLink.remove();

    $(doc.documentElement).removeClass("k-" + oldSkinName).addClass("k-" + skinName);
}

if (animate) {
    preloadStylesheet(url, replaceTheme);
} else {
    replaceTheme();
}
};
```

Comment: Try adding a timestamp on the end of the css url, e.g.: `url + "?_=" + (new Date()).getTime()`.. perhaps this avoid url caching.

Comment: Your suggestion was the answer to our problem. I think you should post it as an answer. I couldn't find any answer to this exact Q on Google/SO yet.

Comment: Ok, I have posted an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a timestamp on the end of the css url, e.g.:

```
url = url + "?_=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

This will avoid url caching.